Web page self-detecting external elements failing to load
I would like to detect in a web page when some of its javascript or css elements have failed to load, and alert the user. I have the below but it does not work.
(The actual use-case involves end-users needing certain certificates installed and if elements fail to load, the page will give them instructions on how to update their browser/OS. But this is a minimum reproducible testcase on my way to that solution.)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <title>Lorum Title Ipsus</title>

    <script>
      
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
        // Monitor <script> elements
        document.querySelectorAll('script[src]').forEach(script => {
            script.addEventListener('error', function() {
            alert('Failed to load script:', script.src);
          }, true);
        });
    
        // Monitor <link rel="stylesheet"> elements
        document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="stylesheet"]').forEach(link => {
            link.addEventListener('error', function() {
            alert('Failed to load stylesheet:', link.href);
          }, true);
        });

      });
      </script>
    <!-- **** NOTE THE OBVIOUS ERROR BELOW -->
    <link href="https://ERRRORcdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    Lorum Ipsus
  </body>
</html>


For synchronous scripts, the DOMContentLoaded event will fire only after they have been (attempted to be) loaded and evaluated. Try a mutation observer to detect the creation of the scripts and immediately attach your error handlers, or try listening to the error event on the document itself (not sure whether it bubbles).

Aha, yes, a document.head.addEventListener("error" does work. My first attempt had failed because I'd mistakenly put the event listener on the body.

@Bergi I'd be happy to accept that as the answer. (Though you're not hurting for reputation, LOL.)

Hm that's weird, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/error_event says it doesn't bubble… but I'm happy to post it as an answer so that you can accept and mark the question as solved (you're right I don't care about rep any longer)

For synchronous scripts, the DOMContentLoaded event will fire only after they have been (attempted to be) loaded and evaluated, so you're missing the error event.
You could try a mutation observer to detect the creation of the scripts and immediately attach your error handlers, or try to attach your error event handlers on the window or document or document.head itself (although it should not bubble).
